# Flask based desktop app, bundled with Chromium embedded framework client

Tags: python, flask, cross-platform, desktop-application, chromium-embedded

I'm trying to develop a cross-platform, Flask-based desktop app (as a local server), bundled with Chromium embedded browser simple window (as a client). The CEF client is implemented separately for Windows and Mac, and although this isn't exactly cross platform, there is practically no work that need's to be done (as far as it could be told at this, initial stage of the project) on the client side, just using the minimum functionality, already provided in CEF simple examples.

Are there any best practices of packaging the two (client and server) together? In the development environment everything works as expected. Starting the client and the server is controlled by a separate Python script, but I'm wondering if there is a better solution to do this (for example, using some methods on the client side to check if server is running, and start it if it isn't...). I'm also wondering if this is a good way for developing cross-platform desktop apps. Perhaps there's an altogether better way of packaging HTML based desktop apps inside a native looking window?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer regarding CEF, but I had a look at two solutions to package an HTML based desktop app inside a native looking window:

- PySide
- Node-Webkit

Using PySide with Flask is quite easy, just add the following script close to your Flask app.py file and it should work directly:

```
import os, urllib, sys, time, json

# import PySide
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtWebKit import *
from PySide.QtCore import *

# import Flask
from app import app as application

class WebApp(QThread):
    def setApplication(self, app, setup_callback):
        self.application = app
        self.setup_callback = setup_callback

    def run(self):
        self.setup_callback()
        self.application.run(use_debugger=True, debug=True, use_reloader=False, port=5000)

def main():
    global web, env

    # Init Flask server
    webappThread = WebApp()
    def setup_callback():
        print 'Do something specific here before app start'
    webappThread.setApplication(application, setup_callback)
    webappThread.start()

    # Init QT app
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Setup WebView (WebKit)
    web = QWebView()
    web.resize(992, 800)
    web.setWindowTitle('Application Name')
    # web.setWindowIcon(QIcon('static/img/icon.png'))
    qr = web.frameGeometry()
    cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
    qr.moveCenter(cp)
    web.move(qr.topLeft())  

    web.setUrl('http://127.0.0.1:5000/')

    # Bind shut down
    def shutdown():
        webappThread.quit()
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(shutdown)

    # Start up
    web.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It opens a window with your HTML displayed in it using Webkit. The problem that I found is that the result look not as good as on a modern web browser meaning that the results was pixelized and slow. However, if this looks OK for you than you have one solution ;)

I am now trying to see if can make python to communicate with node-webkit which looks very promising. I have asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271058/flask-python-node-webkit-perfect-desktop-app) re this but I did not get any answer. If you are interested, have a look at [this example](http://blog.infireal.com/wsgi-node-webkit-2014-03.html). I couldn't not make it work, but it definitely looks promising.